# Difference between type="text/css" and type="text/stylesheet"?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

More out of general interest more than anything, but what's the difference between

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/test.css" type="text/css"/>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/test.css" type="text/stylesheet"/>
```

There appear to be some differences to the style in different browsers, but I can't really point to anything specific - is there any real difference between using either of these?

Comment: You should be using text/css as detailed in the W3C spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html. It's possible some browsers are guessing at text/stylesheet or the webserver has the mime type added and is responding appropriate, or just guessing based on the filename perhaps? Not sure it should be working really!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`text/stylesheet` is **not a valid type** for the `link` element.

You should use `text/css`.

You are probably seeing a difference in browsers because some browsers have taken into account people might incorrectly use `type="text/stylesheet"` instead of `type="text/css"`.