# How to refere a stylesheet in phonegap?

Tags: html, css, cordova, styling

I just wanted to know how to refer the stylesheet which is under css folder in assets/www path. Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>EazyTutor</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="top_header">Home Page</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
@charset 'UTF-8';
#main_wrapper
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
#top_header
{
height:5%;
background-color:#CCC;
}
```

Please help guys...

Comment: Exactly as you have written. What is the problem?

Comment: The style is not working as mentioned in css. :(

Comment: If you developing for iOS you can debug with Safari. If Android you can use http://debug.phonegap.com/ Either way lets you access the console and browser debug tools

Comment: It is working in emulator. But I don't know why It is not working in Eclipse Browser window.. And anybody have an idea how to specify % in css in phonegap development because only px measurement is working for me.

Comment: It works the same way as a normal browser. You need to set your `body` to 100% height / width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/stylesheet">
```

It should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

see [Difference between type="text/css" and type="text/stylesheet"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457812/difference-between-type-text-css-and-type-text-stylesheet)